# how to get next column values from another sheet while drag cell down

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I need to get values in another sheet column wise on same row, while dragging cell downward in another sheet:

```
=OFFSET('Dors & Window'!$D$121,COLUMN()+1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine, just need to change it a bit e.g. if you put the formula in cell B2 of sheet 1:-

```
=OFFSET('Dors & Window'!$D$121,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),0)
```

then pull it across to get the values in the same row and different columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is guesswork as your question seems to lack clarity, but if in row7:

```
=OFFSET('Dors & Window'!$D$121,,ROW()-6)
```

and copy *down* but if not in row6 adjust `-6` to suit.